# Why am I getting a seg fault when tring to input a string?

Tags: c, string

I am using a do while loop as a menu. The user will input a number that corresponds to the command. Then the function that is with that number should come up. I am in need of help for the first case in my switch statement (the name input). When I run the code, a seg fault occurs. Can someone tell me why?

```
#include "defs.h"
#define MAX_CHAR 32

void nameInput(char name[MAX_CHAR + 1]);

int main (void)
{
        int choice = 0;
        char* name[MAX_CHAR + 1] = {0};

    do
    {
            printf("Menu\n");
            printf("1. Name\n");
            printf("2. Enter Years, Party, Office, and State \n");
            printf("3. Enter Age and Sex\n");
            printf("4. Enter Contacts \n");
            printf("5. Enter Contributions and Lies \n");
            printf("6. Display Data \n");
            printf("7. Clear all Data \n");
            printf("8. Quit\n");
            scanf("%d", &choice);

            switch (choice)
            {
                    case 1:
                            nameInput(name[MAX_CHAR + 1]);
                            break;
                    case 2:
                            break;
                    case 3:
                            break;
                    case 4:
                            break;
                    case 5:
                            break;
                    case 6:
                            break;
                    case 7:
                            break;
                    case 8:
                            choice = 8;
                            break;
                    default:
                            printf("Input is invalid\n");
                            break;
            }
    } while(choice != 8);

return (0);
}

void nameInput(char name[MAX_CHAR + 1])
{
        int i = 0;

        printf("Type in the politicians name (max 32 characters):");
        for (i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        {
                scanf("%c", &name[i]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
}
```

Comment: `char* name[MAX_CHAR + 1] = {0};` is defining an array of pointers, not an array of `char`. And `nameInput(name[MAX_CHAR + 1]);` is passing one past the last element of it to the function.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I have changed my char* name to not be a pointer but not I am getting errors saying "making a pointer from an integer without a cast" any ideas?

Comment: `scanf("%c", &name[i]);` reads as single character (leaving all others in `stdin`). To read a name you need `scanf("%32s", name);` (the `32` to insure no more than `32` characters are read, leaving room for the *nul-terminating* character). You should also remove all remaining chars from `stdin` afterwards, e.g. `for (int c = getchar(); c != EOF && c != '\n'; c = getchar()) {}`

Comment: `nameInput(name[MAX_CHAR + 1]);`--> `nameInput(name);`.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Answer (score 5):

Let's start at the beginning. When taking input with `scanf`, you must *always* check the return. You must test for three conditions every time:

1. `EOF` Did the user cancel input by generating a manual `EOF` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> on Linux (or <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> on windows);
2. Is the return less than the number of *conversion specifiers* included in the *format string*? If so, a *matching failure* or *input failure* occurred and character extraction stopped at the point of the error leaving all offending characters in `stdin` unread; and finally
3. The return equals the number of *conversion specifiers* indicating that a valid value was stored in each variable.

(you still must validate that whatever input you received satisfies any constraints you have, e.g. `1 <= choice && choice <= 8`, etc..)

Complicating the `scanf` input picture, all conversions leave the line-ending unread in `stdin`, and further the `%c` and `%[...]` conversion specifiers do not consume leading whitespace. So if either `%c` or `%[...]` is used after any other conversion, you must manually handle the whitespace that remains in `stdin`. You can do that by including a leading `'space'` in your *format string*, or you can properly clean up after yourself using a helper-function to `empty_stdin` (as there is no guarantee the next input will use `scanf`)

To facilitate emptying `stdin` a simple loop that reads all characters that remain until `'\n'` or `EOF` is encountered is all that is needed.

```
void empty_stdin (void)
{
    int c = getchar();

    while (c != EOF && c != '\n')
        c = getchar();
}
```

With the basics covered, let's turn to your problem with `name`. When you declare `name` you need to declare it as a character array, not an array of pointers. To do so, just removed the additional `'*'`, e.g.

```
    int choice = 0;
    char name[MAX_CHAR + 1] = {0};
```

(good job in `#define`'ing a constant for `MAX_CHAR`)

When an array is accessed, the first level of indirection (e.g. the first `[..]`) is converted to a pointer to the first element of the array (see: [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3) -- and note the 4 exceptions). What this means is that `name` is converted to a pointer, including when it is passed as a parameter to a function. So you can use the following in your function declaration:

```
int nameInput(char *name);
```

or

```
int nameInput(char name[]);
```

(both are equivalent and valid)

In fact, you can even include the size information as you have, through it is not necessary.

When you call `nameInput`, you simply include `name` for the same reason -- it is converted to a pointer to the first character. So your call will be:

```
case 1:  nameInput(name);
```

(though we will see you can improve that)

When you create a function that takes input, it needs to provide a meaningful return, not `void`. That way you can use the return to **validate** whether the input succeeded, failed or the user canceled. So instead of `void`, a simple `int` works fine, e.g.

```
int nameInput (char name[])
{
    int rtn;

    printf("Type in the politicians name (max 32 characters): ");

    rtn = scanf (" %32[^\n]", name);

    if (rtn == EOF) {
        fputs ("(user canceled input)\n\n", stdout);
        return -1;
    }
    else if (rtn == 0) {
        empty_stdin();
        return 0;
    }

    empty_stdin();

    return 1;
}
```

(where `-1` is returned if the user cancels, `0` for failure, or `1` indicating successful input)

Putting it altogether, (and tidying up the fact that **one** `printf` is all that is needed for your menu), you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_CHAR 32

void empty_stdin (void)
{
    int c = getchar();

    while (c != EOF && c != '\n')
        c = getchar();
}

int nameInput(char name[]);

int main (void)
{
    int choice = 0;
    char name[MAX_CHAR + 1] = {0};

    do {
            int rtn;    /* variable to hold scanf return */

            printf ("\nMenu\n"
                    "  1. Name\n"
                    "  2. Enter Years, Party, Office, and State \n"
                    "  3. Enter Age and Sex\n"
                    "  4. Enter Contacts \n"
                    "  5. Enter Contributions and Lies \n"
                    "  6. Display Data \n"
                    "  7. Clear all Data \n"
                    "  8. Quit\n\n"
                    "   choice: ");
            rtn = scanf ("%d", &choice);

            if (rtn == EOF) {
                fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stdout);
                break;
            }
            else if (rtn != 1) {
                fputs ("  error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
                empty_stdin();
                continue;
            }
            else {
                putchar ('\n');
                empty_stdin();
            }

            switch (choice)
            {
                    case 1:
                            {
                                int nrtn = nameInput(name);
                                if (nrtn == -1)
                                    goto usercanceled;
                                else if (nrtn == 1)
                                    printf ("\n  stored: %s\n", name);
                            }
                            break;
                    case 2:
                            break;
                    case 3:
                            break;
                    case 4:
                            break;
                    case 5:
                            break;
                    case 6:
                            break;
                    case 7:
                            break;
                    case 8:
                            break;
                    default:
                            printf("  Input is invalid\n");
                            break;
            }
    } while (choice != 8);

    usercanceled:;

    return 0;
}

int nameInput (char name[])
{
    int rtn;

    printf("Type in the politicians name (max 32 characters): ");

    rtn = scanf (" %32[^\n]", name);

    if (rtn == EOF) {
        fputs ("(user canceled input)\n\n", stdout);
        return -1;
    }
    else if (rtn == 0) {
        empty_stdin();
        return 0;
    }

    empty_stdin();

    return 1;
}
```

Now you have a fairly robust menu that can handle invalid input, or the cat stepping on the keyboard, etc... without problems, e.g.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/scanf_menu

Menu
  1. Name
  2. Enter Years, Party, Office, and State
  3. Enter Age and Sex
  4. Enter Contacts
  5. Enter Contributions and Lies
  6. Display Data
  7. Clear all Data
  8. Quit

   choice: foo
  error: invalid integer input.

Menu
  1. Name
  2. Enter Years, Party, Office, and State
  3. Enter Age and Sex
  4. Enter Contacts
  5. Enter Contributions and Lies
  6. Display Data
  7. Clear all Data
  8. Quit

   choice: 1

Type in the politicians name (max 32 characters): Bleach-blond Cheeto

  stored: Bleach-blond Cheeto

Menu
  1. Name
  2. Enter Years, Party, Office, and State
  3. Enter Age and Sex
  4. Enter Contacts
  5. Enter Contributions and Lies
  6. Display Data
  7. Clear all Data
  8. Quit

   choice: 1

Type in the politicians name (max 32 characters): (user canceled input)
```

(**note:** the user can cancel by generating a manual `EOF` at any point and cause a graceful exit to the program)

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

The function `nameInput` expects a pointer and when you call the function with the `name` as an argument, that is `nameInput(name)`, this is equivalent to passing 
the pointer to the first element of array `name`.